# Possible solution set to a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am given an augmented matrix with 
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 5 & 5 & a\\
3 & 2 & 1 & 12\\
0 & 1 & b & 3
\end{array}\right]$$

And I am looking for the possibility of values where the coefficients will be A)no solution
B)infinite solutions
c)one solution

Now typically I would put this in rref to find the value and thereby if it fit A,B, or C but with unknown coefficients I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You go as far as you can with elementary row operations, then ponder what you get.

Comment: Just perform the "algorithm" (Gaussian elimination) with the unknown $b$.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with row operations and distinguish different cases as they come along. Alternatively, you can use the fact that a square system has a unique solution if the determinant of the coefficient matrix is non-zero. Note that:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 5 & 5 \\
3 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & b
\end{vmatrix} = 15-15b$$

Hence:

- If $b \ne 1$, the solution is unique (for all $a$);
- If $\color{blue}{b=1}$: substitute and continue with only the parameter $a$:
  $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0 & 5 & 5 & a\\
  3 & 2 & 1 & 12\\
  0 & 1 & \color{blue}{1} & 3
  \end{array}\right]$$
  Now compare the first and the last row; can you finish (hoover over for hint)?

  > For the system to have solutions, you need $R_1 = 5R_3$, so you need $a=\ldots$.